# how to get the date of first monday of the current year (php)?

Tags: php

how to get the  date of first monday of the current year using php functions

example 04-01-2010

Comment: This does something very similar: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php#77489

Answer (score 8):

Just change the format as wanted :)

```
<php
echo date("d m y", strtotime("first monday of 2010"));
?>
```

Comment: Your example didn't work for me, but with this slight modification, it did: `date("d m y", strtotime("monday", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1)))`

Answer (score 4):

> $date = new DateTime('2015-01 monday');

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be:

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("mon jan 2014"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// this does NOT work
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday of 2010')); // 2018-12-03

// this does work
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first monday of january 2010')); // 2010-01-04
```